# SwiftUI components different alignment in a list of HStack

Tags: swiftui, alignment

Is there a way to get that different views in `HStack` follow different alignments.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            VStack {
                Item(title: "title a",
                     imgLength: 30)
                Item(title: "title b",
                     imgLength: 40)
                Item(title: "title",
                     imgLength: 100)
            }
        }
    }
}
struct Item: View {
    var title: String
    var imgLength: CGFloat
    var offset: CGFloat
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Color.red.frame(width: imgLength, height: imgLength)
                .border(Color.green, width: 2)
                .padding(.trailing)
            Spacer().frame(width: offset)
            Text(title)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

| current | expected |
| --- | --- |
| [current view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dFwS.png) | [expected view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KF28.png) |

I tried `alignmentGuide`.
Seems not work perfectly and the `HStack` also will be out of screen cause the alignment offset.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways: fixed width or grid.

1. Add a fixed width using `.frame(width:)`:

```
struct Item: View {
    var title: String
    var imgLength: CGFloat
    var offset: CGFloat = 50
    
    let firstColumnWidth = 100.0    // <- Column width
    
    var body: some View {
        HStack {
            Color.red.frame(width: imgLength, height: imgLength)
                .border(Color.green, width: 2)
                .frame(width: firstColumnWidth)    // <- Here
                .padding(.trailing)
            Spacer().frame(width: offset)
            Text(title)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}
```

2. Grid:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            HStack {    // <- HStack to push the grid left
                Grid {   // <- Grid here
                    Item(title: "title a",
                         imgLength: 30)
                    Item(title: "title b",
                         imgLength: 40)
                    Item(title: "a very, very long title",
                         imgLength: 100)
                }
                
                Spacer()   // <- push the grid to the leading position
            }
        }
    }
}
struct Item: View {
    var title: String
    var imgLength: CGFloat
    var offset: CGFloat = 50
    
    var body: some View {
        GridRow {    // <- Each grid row
            Color.red.frame(width: imgLength, height: imgLength)
                .border(Color.green, width: 2)
                .padding(.trailing)

            Text(title)
                .fixedSize(horizontal: false, vertical: true)
                .gridColumnAlignment(.leading)    //  <- To ensure alignment of text
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note, `Grid` need iOS 16+